# How do i write Blood Type in Health kit in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, healthkit

I have a HKHealthStore object properly set up, and I am now trying to write user characteristics (i.e Date of Birth, Biological Sex, Blood Type and Fitzpatrick Skin Type). I can’t find that type in `HKQuantityTypeForIdentifier`. How do I write blood type to HealthKit in `Objective-C`? I am trying the following:

```
int Dateofbirth=20-10-1995;

NSLog(@“%d”, Dateofbirth);

sex=gender;

BloodType= A+ve;

Fitzpatrick Skin Type= something;

HKQuantityType* bodytemp = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier];
```

Comment: help me any body please..

Comment: @JAGAT will you plz help me...??

Comment: your code is not even close to actual code. you need to learn how this works on your own

Comment: Sorry for inconvenient but i haven't work on health kit.

Comment: @OscarApeland Thanks for your response.. i have no idea about health kit.. i already check this issue. but i can't find out a proper solution.. so thats why i am posting here.. if u have any idea plz tell me

Answer (score 2):

You may have to use `characteristicTypeForIdentifier:` with `HKBloodType`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKObjectType_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/HKObjectType/characteristicTypeForIdentifier:

Constants from Blood type:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
   HKBloodTypeNotSet = 0,
   HKBloodTypeAPositive,
   HKBloodTypeANegative,
   HKBloodTypeBPositive,
   HKBloodTypeBNegative,
   HKBloodTypeABPositive,
   HKBloodTypeABNegative,
   HKBloodTypeOPositive,
   HKBloodTypeONegative,
} HKBloodType;
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/HKBloodType

Comment: Thanks for your response.. how to modify my code?? will you guide me

Comment: will you help me plz how to do this thing??

Comment: I need to read Blood Group.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to modify user characteristics. The user must update the characteristics themselves in Health.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i can't understand what you are saying is.. you mean user can enter manually in device or some thing?? plz tell me it is priority task for me

Comment: Launch Health, go to the Health Data tab, tap Me, tap the Edit button in the top right, and then Blood Type to set your HealthKit blood type.

Comment: thanks for your response.. my issue is solved i faced some other issue.. plz check the link.."http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596731/displaying-menstruation-details-in-health-kit-app-in-ios" if you have any idea plz tell me

Comment: @satya How was your issue solved? Please be sure to either accept the correct answer or document the solution yourself for future Stack Overflow users reading this question.