# Displaying Menstruation Details in Health Kit App in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I have a health kit object with all the proper setup; however, I am trying to retrieve the menstruation data of health kit.

However, I cannot be able to find out the corresponding type in  `HKQuantityTypeIdentifier` (i.e. `HKCategoryValueMenstrualFlow`).

The `HKCategoryValueMenstrualFlow` is having some of the sub items such as   `HKCategoryValueMenstrualFlowLight`, `HKCategoryValueMenstrualFlowMedium`, `HKCategoryValueMenstrualFlowHeavy`. Using the following method, I am writing my code like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    HKHealthStore *healthStore = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];

    HKCategoryType *q=[NSSet setWithObjects:
    [HKCategoryType categoryTypeForIdentifier:HKCategoryValueMenstrualFlowHeavy],

    [HKCategoryType categoryTypeForIdentifier:HKCategoryValueMenstrualFlowMedium],

    [HKCategoryType categoryTypeForIdentifier:HKCategoryValueMenstrualFlowLight],

    [HKCategoryType categoryTypeForIdentifier:HKCategoryValueMenstrualFlowUnspecified],nil];

    [healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:shareObjectTypes readTypes: healthStore completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

    if(success == YES) {
    }
}
```

I am writing like this. But my doubt is how to show the details in menstruation data in the health kit app. Please tell me anybody by providing me with any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig help me if u have any idea plz tell me

Answer (score 1):

The available type identifier constants are available in the [HealthKit constants reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014710). The type identifier you are looking for is `HKCategoryTypeIdentifierMenstrualFlow`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. but give me any sample code. how to push values from my code to health kit application.. please guide me..